# Since differential forms of odd rank are anti-commutative, what does that mean for multivariable integration?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, differential-forms, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

For differential forms $\alpha\in\Omega^p$ and $\beta\in\Omega^q$, they satisfy the relation
$$\alpha\wedge\beta=(-1)^{pq}\beta\wedge\alpha$$
Thus, odd ranked forms are anti-commutative. At first, this made me think that changing the order of definite integration of a multivariable function would change the sign of the result, but this  is not the case because
$$\int_a^b\int_c^df(x,y)\,dx\,dy = \int_c^d\int_a^bf(x,y)\,dy\,dx$$
What are some results of the anti-commutativity property in (definite or indefinite) integration? Additionally, how is the canceled out in the above example?

Comment: What are $\Omega^p$ and $\Omega^q$?

Comment: I always understood this to be about treating orientation in an additive way. Think about applying Greens/Stokes theorem to an annulus in the plane: the two bounding circles need to be oppositely oriented for the theorem to work. Where the differential forms come into it is using the exterior derivative to "bump up" the differential 1-form integrated along the boundary circles to a 2-form integrated over the area: anticommutativity is going to make all of the signs work out. There is a great [short note](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/forms.pdf) by Terence Tao on this as well.

Comment: @Bernard I didn't want to reference a manifold, but for a manifold $M$, $\Omega^p(M)$ is the set of differential $p$-forms, i.e. maps from $(TM)^p$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I wrote $\Omega^p$ as a kind-of short hand for $\Omega^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ or maybe $\Omega^p(M)$ depending on what the answer-er wants to comment on.

Comment: Though the notation is similar, the integrands one encounters in multivariable calculus are *not* differential forms. One can formulate a notion of multiple/iterated integrals in terms of differential forms, but it requires some fussing with orientations, and minus signs will show up where they would not in multivariable calculus.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question a few days ago, and I think I have stumbled upon the answer. We integrate forms over an oriented manifold (usually a sub-manifold). Let's say we have the following iterated integral:
$$
\int_a^b\!\!\int_{g(y)}^{h(y)} f\ \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
The manifold in this case is the region
$$R=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\ \middle|\ a\leq y\leq b,\ g(y)\leq x\leq h(y)\right\}$$
which can be equivalently written as
$$R=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\ \middle|\ h^{-1}(x)\leq y\leq g^{-1}(x),\ \inf_{[a,b]}{g}\leq x\leq \sup_{[a,b]}{h}\right\}$$
Because of the anti-commutativity of 1-forms,
$$
\int\!\!\!\int_R f\ \mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y = -\int\!\!\!\int_R f\ \mathrm{d}y\wedge\mathrm{d}x
$$
To avoid picking up a minus sign, we must flip the orientation of the region so that
$$
\int\!\!\!\int_R f\ \mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y = \int\!\!\!\int_{R'} f\ \mathrm{d}y\wedge\mathrm{d}x
$$
where $R'$ has the opposite orientation of $R$. How do we express orientation in iterated integration? Let's look at a 1-dimensional example. Recall that
$$
\int_a^b f\ \mathrm{d}x = -\int_b^a f\ \mathrm{d}x
$$
The interval of integration $[a,b]$ is the same on both sides of this equation. The difference is the orientation of that interval. Since we have determined two expressions for the region $R$ earlier, we can say that
$$
\int_a^b\!\!\int_{g(y)}^{h(y)} f\ \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y = \int_{\inf_{[a,b]}\!g}^{\sup_{[a,b]}\!h}\!\!\!\int_{h^{-1}(x)}^{g^{-1}(x)} f\ \mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Here, the order of differential forms is flipped which picks up a minus sign, but the orientation of the manifold (region) also flipped which cancelled it out. Let $c=\inf_{[a,b]}g$ and $d=\sup_{[a,b]}h$. Then, $a=\inf_{[c,d]} h^{-1}$ and $b=\sup_{[c,d]} g^{-1}$ and we can write
$$
\int_{\inf_{[c,d]} h^{-1}}^{\sup_{[c,d]} g^{-1}}\!\!\int_{g(y)}^{h(y)} f\ \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y = \int_{\inf_{[a,b]}\!g}^{\sup_{[a,b]}\!h}\!\!\!\int_{h^{-1}(x)}^{g^{-1}(x)} f\ \mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
By flipping one of the integrals on the right, we recover the original orientation of $R$ and recover the minus sign picked up from flipping our 1-forms:
$$
\int_{\inf_{[c,d]} h^{-1}}^{\sup_{[c,d]} g^{-1}}\!\!\int_{g(y)}^{h(y)} f\ \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y = -\int_{\inf_{[a,b]}\!g}^{\sup_{[a,b]}\!h}\!\!\!\int_{g^{-1}(x)}^{h^{-1}(x)} f\ \mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
In short, when we change order of integration, we automatically change the orientation of the manifold we are integrating because the canonical place to put the limits in iterated integration are such that this is the case.